# OpenSSL can't decrypt data with private key after upgrading to PHP8

Tags: php, openssl

I have a private public .pem files pair which after upgrading docker image to PHP 8 stopped decoding old data (newly encoded is perfectly fine), both files are working okay and PHP and OpenSSL can read them, problem is with data encoded earlier. Trying to decode it returns:

`Can not decrypt; openssl error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`

Most of the solutions on the internet are about bad keys, but keys looks fine, commands what i tried and which are returning me keys are:

1. `openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -check`
2. `openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -pubout > pub.pub` (returned me exact same public key i have)

What else i can try?

Private key .pem structure is next:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIFDjBABgkqhkiG9w0BB..........FsIOeJIsv8ikhYfu1mmuY0/VbI=
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with passing wrong padding, after we upgraded our PHP encryption library to PHP 8 version it started using different RSA padding scheme.